# Convert integer value to ip-address

Tags: c, embedded

How to convert a 32-bit integer value to an ip-address?

I am having `int value=570534080` and want to convert it to `192.168.1.34`.

Comment: You can call `inet_ntoa`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 32-bit integer here, `570534080`, can be splitted into four 8-bit unsigned integers, which are exact the IP address.

```
int value =  570534080; // which is 0x2201a8c0 (0x22, 0x01, 0xa8, 0xc0)
unsigned char *ip = &value;
/* then */
ip[0] == 192;
ip[1] == 168;
ip[2] == 1;
ip[3] == 34;
```

Please notice the endian (big endian / little endian), which makes @KerrekSB's answer reversed.

**EDITED:**

Let's making it clearer.

When talking about IP address and integers, there're actually TWO types of integers we concern about:

1. The integer representation of the IP address: `192.168.1.34` <==> `(((192 * 256 + 168) * 256 + 1) * 256 + 34`
2. The actual data (bit stream maybe) you receive and interpreted in an 32-bit integer, like what this OP provides: `570534080 <==> (0x22, 0x01, 0xa8, 0xc0)(on a little-endian machine) <==> (34.1.168.192)`.

**PLEASE NOTICE THIS IS PLATFORM SPECIFIC AND DANGEROUS!** Since this relies on the byte order of an integer number, which is called endianess.

**AGAIN EDITED:**

Here I'd vote for @DavidHeffernan's comment, which is to use `inet_ntoa`.

Comment: See the comment under my answer. Your solution isn't the "reverse" of mine. Mine is always correct; yours needs to know the platform's endianness.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm sorry but I don't believe your `Mine is always correct;`. Please see my updates.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I didn't check the OP's actual value. I thought it was a numeric IP address, but in fact it's the wire data interpreted as an int.

Answer (score 12):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void) {
    int value=570534080;
    struct in_addr addr = {value};
    printf( "%s", inet_ntoa( addr ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Test: http://ideone.com/RCDgj4

For Windows use `#include <winsock2.h>`

Comment: The inet_ntoa function does not produce a "readable" integer. take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153966/why-do-inet-ntoa-and-inet-ntop-reverse-the-bytes